# how to get the binary values of the bytes stored in byte array

Tags: java

i am working on a project that gets the data from the file into a byte array and adds "0" to that byte array until the length of the byte array is 224 bits. I was able to add zero's but i am unable to confirm that how many zero's are sufficient. So i want to print the file data in the byte array in binary format. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How many bits are in a byte? Answering this question may instruct you how many bytes you need

Comment: 1 byte is represented in 8bits

Comment: And you want 224 bits, so you need how many bytes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For each byte:

- cast to `int` (happens in the next step via automatic widening of `byte` to `int`)
- bitwise-AND with mask 255 to zero all but the last 8 bits
- bitwise-OR with 256 to set the 9th bit to one, making all values exactly 9 bits long
- invoke [`Integer.toBinaryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) to produce a 9-bit String
- invoke `String#substring(1)` to "delete" the leading "1", leaving exactly 8 binary characters (with leading zeroes, if any, intact)

Which as code is:

```
byte[] bytes = "\377\0\317\tabc".getBytes();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b & 255 | 256).substring(1));
}
```

Output of above code (always 8-bits wide):

```
11111111
00000000
11001111
00001001
01100001
01100010
01100011
```

Comment: This prints seven characters for me on occasions. [This alternative answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12310078/474189) works for me.

Comment: Use this: `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0x100 + (int) (b & 0xFF)).substring(1));` to print 8 characters

Comment: @Duncan a bit late, but I fixed the 7-char issue. The key change was to use `b & 255 | 256`

Answer (score 2):

Try [Integer.toString(bytevalue, 2)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29)

Okay, where'd `toBinaryString` come from? Might as well use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with ***BigInteger*** like below example, most especially if you have **256 bit** or longer.

Put your array into a string then start from there, see sample below:

```
String string = "10000010";
BigInteger biStr = new BigInteger(string, 2);

System.out.println("binary: " + biStr.toString(2));
System.out.println("hex: " + biStr.toString(16));
System.out.println("dec: " + biStr.toString(10));
```

**Another example which accepts bytes:**

```
String string = "The girl on the red dress.";

byte[] byteString = string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println("[Input String]: " + string);
System.out.println("[Encoded String UTF-8]: " + byteString);

BigInteger biStr = new BigInteger(byteString);
System.out.println("binary: " + biStr.toString(2)); // binary
System.out.println("hex: " + biStr.toString(16));   // hex or base 16
System.out.println("dec: " + biStr.toString(10));  // this is base 10
```

**Result:**

```
[Input String]: The girl on the red dress.
[Encoded String UTF-8]: [B@70dea4e

binary: 101010001101000011001010010000001100111011010010111001001101100001000000110111101101110001000000111010001101000011001010010000001110010011001010110010000100000011001000111001001100101011100110111001100101110
hex: 546865206769726c206f6e20746865207265642064726573732e
```

---

You can also work to convert **Binary** to **Byte** format

```
try {
   System.out.println("binary to byte: " + biStr.toString(2).getBytes("UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

---

*Note:*
For string formatting for your Binary format you can use below sample

```
String.format("%256s", biStr.toString(2).replace(' ', '0'));  // this is for the 256 bit formatting
```

Answer (score -2):

First initialize the byte array with 0s:

```
byte[] b = new byte[224];
Arrays.fill(b, 0);
```

Now just fill the array with your data. Any left over bytes will be 0.

Comment: what if the file actually has zeros at the end of its data? You wouldn't be able to tell the difference between initialized zeros and actual zeros

Comment: @bohemian, how are data zeros read from file different from normal zeroes..he he :) I dont get it.

Comment: you said "Any left over bytes will be 0", but that's not necessarily true - if the file contains trailing zeros, with your logic it would appear to have not loaded enough data, but it would have