# How to convert a byte to its binary string representation

Tags: java, binary, byte

For example, the bits in a byte `B` are `10000010`, how can I assign the bits to the string `str` literally, that is, `str = "10000010"`.

**Edit**

I read the byte from a binary file, and stored in the byte array `B`. I use `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(B[i]))`.  the problem is

(a) when the bits begin with (leftmost) 1, the output is not correct because it converts `B[i]` to a negative int value.

(b) if the bits begin with `0`, the output ignore `0`, for example, assume `B[0]` has 00000001, the output is `1` instead of `00000001`

Comment: I'm confused; is this a trick?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a `byte` to a string in base 2?

Comment: I just added an answer to another thread for doing this (converting a value to a String of binary digits) which works for `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Char`, `Int`, and `Long`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950845/501113

Comment: String#Format() might be able to handle this, if you told it to use a width of 8. Likewise System.out.printf().

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Use [`Integer#toBinaryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29):

```
byte b1 = (byte) 129;
String s1 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b1 & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(s1); // 10000001

byte b2 = (byte) 2;
String s2 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b2 & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(s2); // 00000010
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/xHojh)**.

Comment: I tried this method. In my case, I read the byte from a binary file, and stored in the byte array `B`. I use `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(B[i]))`.  When I use this methods, the problem is (a) when the bits begins with (leftmost) 1, the output is not correct because it converts `B[i]` to a negative int value. (b) if the bits begins with 0, the output ignore `0`, for example, assume `B[0]` has `00000001`, the output is `1` instead of `00000001`

Comment: @Sean: a) happens because a `byte` in Java is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. Its minimum value is -128 (2^8), and its maximum value is `127`; b) You can easily fix that by using this `String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b)).replace(' ', '0')` to left pad the resulting string with zeros.

Comment: @ João: thanks for your advice. Do you have any idea about how to address (a), how to store the original bit format (begins with 1) into the string?

Comment: @Sean: Yes, just `&` it with `0xFF`.

Comment: @Sean: `& 0xFF` basically converts a `signed byte` to an `unsigned integer`. For example, `-129`, like you said, is represented by `11111111111111111111111110000001`. In this case, you basically want the first (least significant) 8 bits, so you AND (`&`) it with `0xFF` (`00000000000000000000000011111111`), effectively cleaning the 1's to the left that we don't care about, leaving out just `10000001`.

Comment: @Sean: Ah yes, you need to `replace` the result, *after* the `String.format`, like in the example above. Basically, `String.format` left pads the string with spaces up to 8 `%8s`, and then `replace` takes care of replacing those spaces with `0`s.

Comment: I think this example could be improved, because `byte b1 = (byte) 129;` overflows.

Answer (score 48):

I used this. Similar idea to other answers, but didn't see the exact approach anywhere :)

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((b & 0xFF) + 0x100).substring(1));
```

- `0xFF`  = `255` =  `0b11111111` (max value for an unsigned byte)
- `0x100` = `256` = `0b100000000`

The `&` upcasts the byte to an integer. At that point, it can be anything from `[0;255]` (`[0b00000000 ; 0b11111111]`, I excluded the leading 24 bits). Adding `0x100` and then `.substring(1)` ensure there will be leading zeroes.

I timed it compared to [João Silva's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12310078/1268003), and this is over 10 times faster. http://ideone.com/22DDK1 I didn't include Pshemo's answer as it doesn't pad properly.

Comment: hey! got a question about this. I have a Base64 representation string of a PDF, I need to convert into Binary. Basically, Base64->byte->binary.Will this code work?

Comment: What exactly does the + 0x100 do? You're adding 256 to the resulting integer, but why?

Comment: @ConnerDassen It ensures that the binary string is 0 padded. For example, if `b` is `1`, without `+ 0x100` you will just get `"1"` as your string. By adding `1`, you get `100000001`, and if you take the substring ignoring the first character you will get the proper `"00000001"`. If you do not want your string to be padded you can simply use `Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xff)`. The `& 0xff` fixes the negative/two's complement issues

Answer (score 12):

Is this what you are looking for?

converting from String to byte

```
byte b = (byte)(int)Integer.valueOf("10000010", 2);
System.out.println(b);// output -> -126
```

converting from byte to String

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((b+256)%256));// output -> "10000010"
```

Or as João Silva said in his comment to add leading `0` we can format string to length 8 and replace resulting leading spaces with zero, so in case of string like `"    1010"` we will get `"00001010"`

```
System.out.println(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString((b + 256) % 256))
                         .replace(' ', '0'));
```

Answer (score 7):

You could check each bit on the byte then append either 0 or 1 to a string.  Here is a little helper method I wrote for testing:

```
public static String byteToString(byte b) {
    byte[] masks = { -128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 };
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte m : masks) {
        if ((b & m) == m) {
            builder.append('1');
        } else {
            builder.append('0');
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Get each bit of byte and convert to string.
Say byte has 8 bits, and we can get them one by one via bit move. For example, we move the second bit of the byte 6 bits to right, the second bit at last of bit of 8 bits, then and(&) with 0x0001 to clean the front bits.

```
public static String getByteBinaryString(byte b) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {
        sb.append(b >>> i & 1);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: I needed a little-endian solution, and this one was easiest to adapt (by changing the iteration order to 0 -> 7). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can work with ***BigInteger*** like below example, most especially if you have **256 bit** or longer:

```
String string = "10000010";
BigInteger biStr = new BigInteger(string, 2);

System.out.println("binary: " + biStr.toString(2));
System.out.println("hex: " + biStr.toString(16));
System.out.println("dec: " + biStr.toString(10));
```

**Another example which accepts bytes:**

```
String string = "The girl on the red dress.";

byte[] byteString = string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println("[Input String]: " + string);
System.out.println("[Encoded String UTF-8]: " + byteString);

BigInteger biStr = new BigInteger(byteString);
System.out.println("binary: " + biStr.toString(2)); // binary
System.out.println("hex: " + biStr.toString(16));   // hex or base 16
System.out.println("dec: " + biStr.toString(10));  // this is base 10
```

**Result:**

```
[Input String]: The girl on the red dress.
[Encoded String UTF-8]: [B@70dea4e

binary: 101010001101000011001010010000001100111011010010111001001101100001000000110111101101110001000000111010001101000011001010010000001110010011001010110010000100000011001000111001001100101011100110111001100101110
hex: 546865206769726c206f6e20746865207265642064726573732e
```

---

You can also work to convert **Binary** to **Byte** format

```
try {
   System.out.println("binary to byte: " + biStr.toString(2).getBytes("UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

---

*Note:*
For string formatting for your Binary format you can use below sample

```
String.format("%256s", biStr.toString(2).replace(' ', '0'));  // this is for the 256 bit formatting
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will demonstrate how a java int can be split up into its 4 consecutive bytes.
We can then inspect each byte using Java methods compared to low level byte / bit interrogation.

This is the expected output when you run the code below:

```
[Input] Integer value: 8549658

Integer.toBinaryString: 100000100111010100011010
Integer.toHexString: 82751a
Integer.bitCount: 10

Byte 4th Hex Str: 0
Byte 3rd Hex Str: 820000
Byte 2nd Hex Str: 7500
Byte 1st Hex Str: 1a

(1st + 2nd + 3rd + 4th (int(s)) as Integer.toHexString: 82751a
(1st + 2nd + 3rd + 4th (int(s)) ==  Integer.toHexString): true

Individual bits for each byte in a 4 byte int:
00000000 10000010 01110101 00011010
```

Here is the code to run:

```
public class BitsSetCount
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int send = 8549658;

        System.out.println( "[Input] Integer value: " + send + "\n" );
        BitsSetCount.countBits(  send );
    }

    private static void countBits(int i) 
    {
        System.out.println( "Integer.toBinaryString: " + Integer.toBinaryString(i) );
        System.out.println( "Integer.toHexString: " + Integer.toHexString(i) );
        System.out.println( "Integer.bitCount: "+ Integer.bitCount(i) );

        int d = i & 0xff000000;
        int c = i & 0xff0000;
        int b = i & 0xff00;
        int a = i & 0xff;

        System.out.println( "\nByte 4th Hex Str: " + Integer.toHexString(d) );
        System.out.println( "Byte 3rd Hex Str: " + Integer.toHexString(c) );
        System.out.println( "Byte 2nd Hex Str: " + Integer.toHexString(b) );
        System.out.println( "Byte 1st Hex Str: " + Integer.toHexString(a) );

        int all = a+b+c+d;
        System.out.println( "\n(1st + 2nd + 3rd + 4th (int(s)) as Integer.toHexString: " + Integer.toHexString(all) );

        System.out.println("(1st + 2nd + 3rd + 4th (int(s)) ==  Integer.toHexString): " + 
                Integer.toHexString(all).equals(Integer.toHexString(i) ) );

        System.out.println( "\nIndividual bits for each byte in a 4 byte int:");

        /*
         * Because we are sending the MSF bytes to a method
         * which will work on a single byte and print some
         * bits we are generalising the MSF bytes
         * by making them all the same in terms of their position
         * purely for the purpose of printing or analysis
         */
        System.out.print( 
                    getBits( (byte) (d >> 24) ) + " " + 
                    getBits( (byte) (c >> 16) ) + " " + 
                    getBits( (byte) (b >> 8) ) + " " + 
                    getBits( (byte) (a >> 0) ) 
        );


    }

    private static String getBits( byte inByte )
    {
        // Go through each bit with a mask
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for ( int j = 0; j < 8; j++ )
        {
            // Shift each bit by 1 starting at zero shift
            byte tmp =  (byte) ( inByte >> j );

            // Check byte with mask 00000001 for LSB
            int expect1 = tmp & 0x01; 

            builder.append(expect1);
        }
        return ( builder.reverse().toString() );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry i know this is a bit late... But i have a much easier way...
To binary string :

```
//Add 128 to get a value from 0 - 255
String bs = Integer.toBinaryString(data[i]+128);
bs = getCorrectBits(bs, 8);
```

getCorrectBits method :

```
private static String getCorrectBits(String bitStr, int max){
    //Create a temp string to add all the zeros
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < (max - bitStr.length()); i ++){
        sb.append("0");
    }

    return sb.toString()+ bitStr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer.toBinaryString((byteValue & 0xFF) + 256).substring(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String byteToBinaryString(byte b){
    StringBuilder binaryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        binaryStringBuilder.append(((0x80 >>> i) & b) == 0? '0':'1');
    return binaryStringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer could be:

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})); // 0
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1})); // 1
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0})); // 256
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0})); // 65536
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0})); // 16777216
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0})); // 4294967296
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})); // 1099511627776
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})); // 281474976710656
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})); // 72057594037927936
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})); // 18446744073709551616
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})); // 4722366482869645213696
System.out.println(new BigInteger(new byte[]{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})); // 1208925819614629174706176
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);                                              // 9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 0):

We all know that Java does not provide anything like the unsigned keyword. Moreover, a `byte` primitive according to the Java's spec represents a value between `−128` and `127`. For instance, if a `byte` is `cast` to an `int` Java will interpret the first `bit` as the `sign` and use sign extension.

#### Then, how to convert a byte greater than `127` to its binary string representation ??

Nothing prevents you from viewing a `byte` simply as 8-bits and interpret those bits as a value between `0` and `255`. Also, you need to keep in mind that there's nothing you can do to force your interpretation upon someone else's method. If a method accepts a `byte`, then that method accepts a value between `−128` and `127` unless explicitly stated otherwise.

So the best way to solve this is convert the `byte` value to an `int` value by calling the `Byte.toUnsignedInt()` method or casting it as a `int` primitive `(int) signedByte & 0xFF`. Here you have an example:

```java
public class BinaryOperations
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte forbiddenZeroBit = (byte) 0x80;

        buffer[0] = (byte) (forbiddenZeroBit & 0xFF);
        buffer[1] = (byte) ((forbiddenZeroBit | (49 << 1)) & 0xFF);
        buffer[2] = (byte) 96;
        buffer[3] = (byte) 234;

        System.out.println("8-bit header:");
        printBynary(buffer);
    }

    public static void printBuffer(byte[] buffer)
    {
        for (byte num : buffer) {
            printBynary(num);
        }
    }

    public static void printBynary(byte num)
    {
        int aux = Byte.toUnsignedInt(num);
        // int aux = (int) num & 0xFF; 
        String binary = String.format("%8s', Integer.toBinaryString(aux)).replace(' ', '0');
        System.out.println(binary);
    }
}
```

#### Output

```sh
8-bit header:
10000000
11100010
01100000
11101010
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another hint for those who need to massively convert bytes to binary strings: Use a lookup table instead of using those String operation all the time. This is a lot faster than calling the convert function over and over again

```
public class ByteConverterUtil {

  private static final String[] LOOKUP_TABLE = IntStream.range(0, Byte.MAX_VALUE - Byte.MIN_VALUE + 1)
                                                        .mapToObj(intValue -> Integer.toBinaryString(intValue + 0x100).substring(1))
                                                        .toArray(String[]::new);

  public static String convertByte(final byte byteValue) {
    return LOOKUP_TABLE[Byte.toUnsignedInt(byteValue)];
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(convertByte((byte)0)); //00000000
    System.out.println(convertByte((byte)2)); //00000010
    System.out.println(convertByte((byte)129)); //10000001
    System.out.println(convertByte((byte)255)); //11111111
  }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just guessing here, but if you have a Byte then couldn't you simply invoke toString() on the object to get the value? Or, glancing at the [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#byteValue%28%29), using byteValue()?