# Can't convert byte to normal view

Tags: java, byte

I have long value, which i want to convert ot byte array. I use this function

```
      public static byte[] longToByteArray(long value) {
        byte[] result = new byte[8];
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          result[i] = (byte)(value & 0xFF);
          System.out.println(result[i]);
          System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result[i]));
          value >>>= 8;
        } 
        return result;
      }
```

and output data looks like

```
18
10010
-12
11111111111111111111111111110100
88
1011000
83
1010011
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Why i have too much 1 in binary view of -12, and how can i get it like

```
11110100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `Integer.toBinaryString(result[i])` converts your byte to int (32 bits), and also, bytes are represented from -128 to 127, so values grater than 127 are being represented as negative numbers; hence, your byte ends up being a negative int. to solve it you can change this line:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result[i]));
```

for this one:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result[i] & 0xFF));
```

Comment: -12 is a negative integer.

Also, I think you meant `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result[i] & 0xFF));` (single `&`)

Comment: @EvanKnowles sure it is, is there anything you want to clarify?

Comment: @EvanKnowles you're right, it is '&', not '&&', I'm going to delete my answer, can you please add the lines to your answer? the OP also asked for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Your `-12` is coming out as `11111111111111111111111111110100` because it is a negative number encoded in 2's complement format using all 32-bits available to it as it is being parsed as an integer.

If you only want the final 8 bits, you'll probably have to format it like that. Check this answer: [How to convert a byte to its binary string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310017/how-to-convert-a-byte-to-its-binary-string-representation)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that even though you do `(byte)(value & 0xFF)`  when you call `Integer.toBinaryString` it is being converted back to a 32 bit integer and you are getting proper output for -12 integer.

One simple solution is to convert negative byte values (-128 to -1) to be positive unsigned byte values (128 to 255).   This is done simply by testing for negative and adding 256, like such:

```
int b = (int)(value & 0xFF);
if (b<0) {
    b = b + 256;
}
```

This is done in an integer data type, but the resulting value is 0..255 which is appropriate for an unsigned byte.   So now, it turns out, instead of `-12` you will have `244` but it turns out that the binary representation of 244 is the same as an 8-bit version of -12.   Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [JBBP](https://code.google.com/p/java-binary-block-parser/)

```
byte [] packed = JBBPOut.BeginBin().Long(aLongValue).End().toByteArray();
```