# Converting a hexadecimal String to byte array

Tags: javascript, node.js, evernote

My question is:
 how to successfully use the method `getResourceByHash(...)` of Evernote API?

What I have done:
I have got the hex hash of em-media in the note content: `80ad525cd14de8f925487c02afc9ab21`

Then I use the following function to turn the hexadecimal `String` to bytes:

```
function hex2bin(hex){
    var bytes = [];
    for(var i=0; i< hex.length-1; i+=2) {
        bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes);    
}

var bin = hex2bin("80ad525cd14de8f925487c02afc9ab21");
```

At next I apply the variable to the function `getResourceByHash(...)`  in this way:

```
noteStore.getResourceByHash(GUID, bin, true, true, true, 
    function(err,result){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

But the output turns out:

```
{identifier: 'Resources', key: 'c280c2ad525cc3914dc3a8c3b925487c02c2afc389c2ab21'}
undefined
```

In all, I am confused.

Comment: Depending on your provided data, there is an error while converting hex to binary or passing that value to the function: the key `c280c2ad525cc3914dc3a8c3b925487c02c2afc389c2ab21`could not be binary as it contains letters, instead it is the almost same except the trailing "c2" whereever you're adding it.

Comment: thx, I also suspect the wrong converting of the function hex2bin. and do u know the correct ways to do that? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further, you cannot simply push a value of type `Integer` to a byte array. Integers are represented with 32 bit (4 bytes), so you first have to "split" such number while computing the single bytes one by one:

```
intToByteArray = function(intToConvert) {
    var byteArray = new Array(4)

    for(var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
        var byte = intToConvert & 0xff;
        byteArray[i] = byte;
        intToConvert = (intToConvert - byte) / 256 ;
    }

    return byteArray;
};
```

[Demonstration of back and forth conversion (JS-Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/fy7ecw8v/1/)

---

## Explanation of code lines

1. At first, we declare an array of bytes:

   ```
   var byteArray = new Array(4)
   ```

   > Array: [00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000]
2. By using the [bit-wise `AND` operator `&`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND), we "capture" the first 8 bits while assigning the resulting value to a new variable:

   ```
   var byte = intToConvert & 0xff;
   ```

   > What's happening with our variables:
   >
   > ```
   > intToConvert: 10101010 10101010 10101010 10101010
   >
   > AND "0xff":   11111111 -------- -------- --------
   >
   > Results in:   10101010
   > ```
3. Then, we put the resulting single byte to the actual index of the temporary byte array:

   ```
   byteArray[i] = byte;
   ```

   > Array: [10101010, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000]
4. Now, we only have to subtract the value just added to the array and remove one byte from the integer variable:

   ```
   intToConvert = (intToConvert - byte) / 256 ;
   ```

   > 2863311530 - 170 = 2863311360 
   >   2863311360 / 256 = 11184810
   >
   > ```
   > 2863311360 => 10101010 10101010 10101010 00000000
   >   11184810 =>          10101010 10101010 10101010
   > ```

Continuing with this loop will transfer byte by byte from the Integer to the temporary byte array. So we will get a byte array of 4 single bytes representing one integer or two `Character` of the hexadecimal `String`.

---

How to convert `byte` to `Integer` [is well explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310017/how-to-convert-a-byte-to-its-binary-string-representation/17496691#17496691).
So your updated `hex2bin(String)` should look like:

```
function hex2bin(hexString) {
    var bytes = new Array(hexString.length / 2);

    for(var i = 0; i < hexString.length-1; i+=2) {
        bytes.push(
            intToByteArray(
                parseInt(hexString.substr(i, 2), 16)
            )
        );
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 8);
    for(byte b : bytes) {
        sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString((b & 0xFF) + 0x100).substring(1));    
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: well, It doesn't work.The converting result  applied to the function will  output `[Error:Cannot read length of binary data]` According to the [link](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceByHash) the contenthash parameter should be a string. And what's more , even if I change ur ways to output string, It still doesnt work..

Comment: So I must had found a class from another package, sorry for that. How do you "change my way to output string"? The expected value is  11000010100000001100001010101101010100100101110011000011100100011001101110000111010100011000011101110010010010101001000011111001011000010101011111100001110001001110000101010101100100001