# Restricting Binary Output to 8 bits

Tags: java

How Can I solve this problem in java ?

```
int mask = ~0;

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(mask));
```

When I type this, the output becomes: `11111111111111111111111111111111`
However I just want to get 8 bits `(11111111)`.

Another example is,

```
int left = mask << 7;

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(left));
```

Output of these two lines is: `11111111111111111111111110000000`
How can I take the last 8 bit ? `(10000000)`.

Comment: Have you tried using `& 0xff` to restrict the result to 8 bits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a byte to its binary string representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310017/how-to-convert-a-byte-to-its-binary-string-representation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type int has 4 bytes,every byte has 8 bits,so when you call toBinaryString of Integer class,you get 32 bit String.

You can use code below to achieve your goal.

```
int mask = ~0;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(mask & 0xFF));
int left = mask << 7;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(left & 0xFF));
```

I hope the code will help you.