# Huffman codes. Decompression stage. How to extract byte array(or byte-by-byte) from file .bin in a list<int> which will be an 8-bit array

Tags: c#, .net, huffman-code, binaryreader, binarywriter

I'm trying to implement Huffman compression and decompression of .txt file. Compression works fine: in brief, I build binary tree where symbols are leafs, encode each symbol with `List<int>` of 0's and 1's, form a long string of that 0's and 1's for the whole text(by `Join` method) and write each 8-bit word(contains 8 binary digits, which were just of `Char`) to the file. Wow, file decreased in size!

Now on the next stage - DECOMPRESSION - I need to read byte by byte from file using `BinaryReader`, for example, and convert it to `List<int>` or `String` again, but not to convert to `int` or `char`, which occupy 4 or 1 bytes respectively.

P.S That's my assumption. Maybe are there better ideas? I would like to know how to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've already created a binary tree where the leafs corresponds to all of the different characters, right? That's all information you need have to decompress/decode the binary file.

There's a good explanation from [Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/huffman-decoding/):

> 1. We start from root and do following until a leaf is found.
> 2. If current bit is 0, we move to left node of the tree.
> 3. If the bit is 1, we move to right node of the tree.
> 4. If during traversal, we encounter a leaf node, we print character of that particular leaf node and then again continue the iteration of
>      the encoded data starting from step 1

You know there's a **leaf node** when there's no child nodes either to the right or to the left in the tree.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Warcaith, thanks for your answer, but I just wanted to know how simply get my string of 0's and 1's back from the binary file. I found that I could read byte-by-byte and obtain it's binary representation using `Convert.ToString(byte, 2)`.

Comment: But now I realized that there could be troubles when byte starts with `0`. Here is the same problem discussed for java [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/12310017/12505219)

Comment: Oh, right, I think I misunderstood you, sorry! If you've found a solution, be sure to make an **Answer** so other programmers can make use of your post! :)

Comment: Yep, but after I overcome bugs of `Convert.ToString(byte,2)` approach. But it's definitely a good one!

Comment: Have you tried to decode your file with your solution? Did you get back the old text or did you have troubles with the `0` at the beginning?

Comment: What I don't get is why you need to save the char's as 8-bit values to the binary file. Shouldn't the binary file just be used for traversing the binary tree and find what character correspond to that specific leaf?

Comment: No, you didn't get. The key principle of Huffman is that it produces smart encoding. The more frequency of symbol in text the lesser should be it's prefix/binary code(the closer to the root it'll be in binary tree). I write not an 8bit per symbol, but amount of bits in encoding per symbol. For example if any char C is 8-bit long definitely , and huffman approaches shows that C will be 3-bit encoded, then I'll write 3 bits instead of 8

Comment: And I need to work with files, not just in console of IDE

Comment: Yes, I know how Huffman coding works and you are completely correct. I just thought that you was writing each character as 8-bit which made me a bit confused as it would be impossible to get back the encoded file if you were to traverse the tree with a binary file like that!