# Why does the java method Integer.toBinaryString(-128) output seven digits?

Tags: java, binary, byte, twos-complement

The simple scenario:
You have a byte array

`byte[] message = { 1, 2, 3 };`

To print it out in binary you can use the code:

```
for (byte b : message) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0x100 + b).substring(1));
}
```

(Got that code from [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393873/how-to-get-the-binary-values-of-the-bytes-stored-in-byte-array))

And get this output:

```
00000001
00000010
00000011
```

But if you tag a -128 on the end...

`byte[] message = { 1, 2, 3, -128 };`

```
00000001
00000010
00000011
0000000
```

WOAH! A seven digit binary number? I sense that this is something to do with two's complement, but the more I try to read on it, the more I get confused. I was expecting `10000000` to appear in the fourth line instead...

**Can anyone explain why `Integer.toBinaryString` of `-128` is seven digits in relatively simple terms?**

[Ye olde javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) says `The unsigned integer value is the argument plus 2^32 if the argument is negative; otherwise it is equal to the argument. This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra leading 0s.`
But like I said... just confuses me.

The context of this whole thing is that I'm trying out coding some of the SHA functions in java. Don't ask me why, I don't even know... I'm just curious/challenging myself/frustrating myself :)

The padding of a message for use in the SHA-256 function (making it a multiple of 512 in bit length) according to [the documentation](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf) is the concatenation of:

1. The original message
2. A single `1` bit
3. `0` bits up to the last 64 bits
4. The original message length as a 64-bit value

Since my messages will most likely be in ASCII 8-bit codes, I simply need to tag a `10000000` in for #2... then I can just count the number of `0` BYTES to add in, I shouldn't have to plan for messages that aren't multiples of 8. The issue is making that `10000000`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(-128 + 0x100) =
(256 - 128) = 128 = 
0b10000000

Integer.toBinaryString(0b10000000) = "10000000"

"10000000".substring(1) = "0000000"
```

Comment: This is why I shouldn't be allowed to code at night. Sorry for the time wasting haha

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in the stack overflow thread you copied from. `0x100` is 256 in decimal, so...

```
0x100 + 1 = 257 = 0b100000001 (9 digits)
0x100 + (-128) = 128 = 0b10000000 (8 digits)
```

In other words, since 128 is less than Byte.MAX_VALUE, you don't get the padding effect that the poster intended.  You can choose a bigger value to pad -- try 0x200 and strip the first two characters??

FWIW, it's understandable these types of bugs b/c negative byte values are a bit of a weird java thing.  Oh well.

Comment: So in the context of what I was trying to accomplish... Does the byte in the array equal 10000000, even if the way I displayed it didn't? Is there some other way I should be inserting a 1 as the SHA function required?

Comment: In reality I won't be displaying the binary... I was just doing that to check if it was working... I just need to have a byte array with the message followed by a 10000000 that will work in bitwise operations.